# How to get list asp.net web API identity users (and delete,put).. for ASP.NET WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }
```

ServiceController.cs

```
public class ServiceController : ApiController
{
    

    [Route("api/user/register")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IdentityResult Register(AccountModel model)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
        user.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;
        user.FullName = model.FullName;
        user.TcNo = model.TcNo;
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 3
        };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, model.Password);
        return result;
        
    }
```

Web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-M6EQ5IM\EREN;Initial Catalog=AkunsemDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

QUESTİON

How to get list asp.net web API identity users (and delete,put).. for ASP.NET WEB API?

```
    [Route("api/user/userlist")]
    [HttpGet]????????????????
    ????????????????
```

Answer (score 1):

In the UserManager helper class, there is the [Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt151669%28v%3Dvs.108%29) property so you  can query them.

Also, I would highly recommend you use Dependency Injection in your API. You can take a look at a sample using ASP.NET Identity [here](https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/blob/master/AspnetIdentitySample/Controllers/UserAdminController.cs)

Comment: Thanks, but this MVC I did not understand anything and I haven't Views folder. Would you be more explanatory for me pls?

Comment: Mvc and WebAPI are not so different. I linked this specific controller because it shows what you can do with the UserManager, and exposes the actions you want. You can take ideas from the implementation of each action there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UserManager is a good option but if you want to do more complex queries, The best option is dbcontext. IdentityDbContext will add these tables to your database.

[image]

So you can write any LINQ queries based on your requirements.
example code to get all role claims

```
var claims = (from ur in _context.UserRoles
          where ur.UserId == user.Id
          join r in _context.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
          join rc in _context.RoleClaims on r.Id equals rc.RoleId
          select rc)
```